# XMLUnit throws NullPointerException when creating Diff object for valid xml

Tags: java, xml, nullpointerexception, xmlunit

I am using `org.custommonkey.xmlunit; (version 1.2)`.
While building `Diff` object:
 `Diff diff = new Diff(expected, generated);`

I always have NullPointerException as it's failing on `this.controlDoc = this.getManipulatedDocument(controlDoc);`.
While debugging I found that in first constructor:

```
public Diff(String control, String test) throws SAXException, IOException {
        this((Reader)(new StringReader(control)), (Reader)(new StringReader(test)));
    }
```

there are proper xmls however when:

```
public Diff(Reader control, Reader test) throws SAXException, IOException {
        this(XMLUnit.buildDocument(XMLUnit.newControlParser(), control), XMLUnit.buildDocument(XMLUnit.newTestParser(), test));
    }
```

is called I see in debugger `[#document: null]`. Why is that so? I tried with many xmls, even really easy and small which I found in internet but nothing works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, I just have found that `XMLUnit.setIgnoreWhitespace(true);` cause this problem because in project I am using Saxon library in ancient version and it was fixed in version 8.9 however this:

```
XMLUnit.setTransformerFactory("org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl");
```

helps a lot.